# Rest and JPA, force Jersey the use of auto-increment instead of JSON object value?

Tags: java, json, rest, jpa, jersey

Ok so I am using Jersey for my REST services, and I'm trying to persist a batch of objects received in JSON.

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="element", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"key","value"}))
public classElement implements Serializable {

    @Id
@NotNull
private long key;

@NotBlank
@Size(max=30)
private String value;

@NotBlank
@Size(max=12)
private String more;

@NotNull 
private long userid;
```

And this is my "create" method:

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public Response createRecord(List<Element> elements) throws Exception{

    for(Element element : elements){

        violations = validator.validate(element);       
        if (violations.size() > 0) {

         jsonResponse.setSuccess(false);
         jsonResponse.setMessage("Error");
         jsonResponse.setValidationError(this.getValidationErrorList());    

        } 
        else {
            em.persist(valeur);  
        }
        jsonResponse.setSuccess(true);
        jsonResponse.setMessage("Success");
 }


    return Response.ok().entity(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(jsonResponse)).build();

}
```

This works nicely when I have a json containing the **value, more, and userid fields**. The key gets an auto-incremented value. But the problem is, in my context I can't validate everything the "user" sends. So it is possible to send the json with the above fields AND the **key** (primary key). So I get a SQLError (duplicate entry) when it is persisted.

So my question (finally): What exactly happens when I do not specify any key and it gets an "auto" value, and how can I reproduce this even when the key is specify? (I.E. ignore the json key field and have the same auto-incremented value I would get without the field)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why coundn't you validate everything the user sends? If no ID is expected and an ID is sent, it should be signalled as an error. Anyway, if you still want to accept messages with ID, but want to ignore them, then simply set the ID to null before calling persist().

Comment: I cannot set a long to null. (But to be honest I didnt even think of setting the key to null before seeing your comment, had a long day..!)

Comment: Set it to 0: the default value it has when a user submit a message without ID.

Comment: I was about to tell you that I tried and it didnt quite cut it. But then I realised that what you are saying makes a lot of sense struck me, and had a look back at my code. Turns out it **does** work. But I have another problem with my uniqueConstraints, the SQLError just looks similar.... well, thanks a lot!